Accept a Syncthing device and a shared folder via command line
I am at a company and we would like to know if it is possible to add-accept a remote computer and a shared folder via Syncthing without graphically interacting with the remote machine, but entirely via command line.
The ideal would be to do everything via command line so as not to disturb the end user.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
